# Any way to hide the "New App for Office" warning for on-premise apps?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, office365-apps

I finally created my first App for Office, and talked IT into deploying it into our on-premise SharePoint App Catalog. Is there any way, in SharePoint 2013, to hide/bypass the security dialog for people who are visiting the page for the first time?

Here's the dialog box I'm talking about,
[image: https://41ab9d6c96ec068e28e2b703c312340b10d51e73.googledrive.com/host/0B00xjPffGU3CcXB3cFpweWF6M1k/want_to_hide.PNG]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to disable this dialog; the end user must click "Start" in order to trust the app. This dialog will not reappear once the user has trusted the app for the first time.

Comment: I so wish this _wasn't_ true, at least for running the workbook in Excel Services.